# C++ Buffer de caracteres adicionando caracteres inexistentes

Tags: android, c++, opengl, android-ndk, jni

Bom, tenho um aplicativo para android que utiliza OpenGL ES 3.1, fiz todo o procedimento para compilar os sombreadores, decidi coloca-los em uma pasta separada em assets, para recuperar o conteúdo eu estou utilizando [AAssetManager](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/asset#group___asset_1ga5630b1f1aa5cd363303018cb2f12f95c).

Código java para recuperar os ativos e activity principal:

```
package com.samuelives.hautingground;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import com.samuelives.hautingground.engine.IESurface;

public class Main extends AppCompatActivity{

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("HGround-Lib");
    }

    private IESurface mGameSurface = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        startGame();
        loadAsset(getAssets());

        //Init Surface
        mGameSurface = new IESurface(this);

        setContentView(mGameSurface);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mGameSurface.onPause();
        pauseGame();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mGameSurface.onResume();
        resumeGame();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        closeGame();
    }

    public native void startGame();
    public native void closeGame();
    public native void pauseGame();
    public native void resumeGame();
    public native void loadAsset(AssetManager manager);
}
```

Código C++ para se comunicar com o código java:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <android/asset_manager_jni.h>
#include <android/asset_manager.h>
#include <GLES3/gl31.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "game/GameMain.h"

GameMain *game = NULL;

extern "C" {

/*    IERender    */

GLuint shader = 0;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_samuelives_hautingground_engine_IERender_initGL(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance)
{

    __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "IERender Native", "initGl called");

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "Native Render", "GL Version: %s", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "Native Render", "GL Extensions: %s", glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS));
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "Native Render", "GL Vendor: %s", glGetString(GL_VENDOR));
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "Native Render", "GL Shading: %s", glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION));
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "Native Render", "GL Render: %s", glGetString(GL_RENDERER));

    game->init();
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_samuelives_hautingground_engine_IERender_drawGL(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance)
{
    game->render();
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_samuelives_hautingground_engine_IERender_resizeGL(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jint w, jint h)
{
    __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "IERender Native", "resizeGl called");
    game->resizeRender(w, h);
}

/*    Main    */

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_samuelives_hautingground_Main_startGame(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance)
{
    game = new GameMain();
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_samuelives_hautingground_Main_closeGame(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance)
{
    delete game;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_samuelives_hautingground_Main_pauseGame(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance)
{

}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_samuelives_hautingground_Main_resumeGame(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance)
{

}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_samuelives_hautingground_Main_loadAsset(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jobject manager)
{

    AAssetManager *mgr = AAssetManager_fromJava(env, manager);
    game->loadShaders(mgr);

}

}
```

E aqui está o código para recuperar o conteúdo dos arquivos:

```
void GameMain::loadShaders(AAssetManager *mgr)
{

    AAssetDir *shadersDir = AAssetManager_openDir(mgr, "shaders");
    if(shadersDir == NULL){
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "AAsset Manager", "Shaders dir not found");
        return;
    }

    const char*fileName;

    while((fileName = AAssetDir_getNextFileName(shadersDir)) != NULL){

        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "AAsset Manager", "Current file %s \n", fileName);

        if(strcmp(fileName, "fragment.fs") != 0){

            AAsset *fragmentAsset = AAssetManager_open(mgr, "shaders/fragment.fs", AASSET_MODE_STREAMING);
            if(fragmentAsset == NULL){
                __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "AAsset Manager", "Fragment file not found");
                break;
            }

            off_t fragmentLength = AAsset_getLength(fragmentAsset);
            char *fragmentBuffer = (char*)malloc(fragmentLength);

            AAsset_read(fragmentAsset, fragmentBuffer, fragmentLength);

            fragmentSource = std::string(fragmentBuffer);
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "AAsset Manager", "Fragment Length: %d .", fragmentLength);
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "AAsset Manager", "Fragment: %s .", fragmentBuffer);

            free(fragmentBuffer);
            AAsset_close(fragmentAsset);

        }else if(strcmp(fileName, "vertex.vs") != 0){

            AAsset *vertexAsset = AAssetManager_open(mgr, "shaders/vertex.vs", AASSET_MODE_STREAMING);
            if(vertexAsset == NULL){
                __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "AAsset Manager", "Vertex file not found");
                break;
            }

            off_t vertexLength = AAsset_getLength(vertexAsset);
            char *vertexBuffer = (char*)malloc(vertexLength);

            AAsset_read(vertexAsset, vertexBuffer, vertexLength);

            vertexSource = std::string(vertexBuffer);
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "AAsset Manager", "Vertex Length: %d .", vertexLength);
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "AAsset Manager", "Vertex: %s .", vertexBuffer);

            free(vertexBuffer);
            AAsset_close(vertexAsset);

        }

    }

    AAssetDir_close(shadersDir);

    m_Render->setShadersSource(vertexSource, fragmentSource);

}
```

Acontece que o buffer esta adicionando caracteres inexistentes em arquivos nulos, inclusive pensei que um plugin que instalei no android studio para formatar o código glsl estaria adicionando estes caracteres, mas mesmo depois de desinstalar e verificar no windows explorer que o arquivo estava com tamanho 0.

Eis a saída:

[image: Saída do compilador de shaders]

[image: Saída do log]

Note que ele também altera a ordem dos caracteres, por exemplo eis um trecho de um shader:

```
#version 300 es

//fragment
```

A saída no log é a seguinte: #version 300 es //fragmentmll

O que pode esta causando esta desordem?

Comment: posta o conteúdo do shader, afinal de contas a mensagem diz quem tem um caractere inválido no arquivo de shader e não consegue compilá-lo.

Answer (score 0):

Eu sou sou muito perito em Java nem em OpenGl.

Mas já mexi bastante com programas em CUDA ( nvidia ) com códigos em C, C++ e Delphi misturado. E um problema que tende a ocorrer bastante é compatibilidade de tipos.

Por exemplo, em uma certa linguagem um `Int` pode ser ocupar **2 bytes** e ser do tipo **signed**, enquanto em outra pode ocupar **4 bytes** podendo ser **signed** ou **unsigned**. Como na verdade o maquina não conhece tipos de dados, ela apenas recebe uma sequencia de bits e a interpreta da forma que for ordenada.
E é ai que vem o problema: um dado foi armazenado numa interpretação num código de uma linguagem de programação, e foi obtido e manuseado com outro pelo outro código da outra linguagem.

---

Como vi pelos prints que está reclamando de caracteres desconhecidos, cheguei a tal conclusão:

Java armazena caracteres em espaços de **2 bytes** sem sinal (**unsigned**), que vai de 0 a 65.535, como informado [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689549/range-of-char-in-java),
já C/C++ os armazena com **1 byte** com sinal (**signed**), que vai do valor -128 até +127.

Os caracteres convencionais  pertencem à tabela [ASCII](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), que compõem um total de 128 caracteres.

O problema deve ter sido que em java um caractere de código 238 ( por exemplo) foi posto num char em C/C++, e por isso não reconheceu o caractere ( pois não pertence à tabela ASCII).

---

Tente verificar os tipos e imprimir o conteúdo das string através de ambas linguagens sendo usadas, para assim saber o que está acontecendo por dentro, e então corrigir fazendo uma conversão apropriada de tipos.

Comment: Isso é meio estranho, AAssetManager_fromJava deveria recuperar a referência do gerenciador de assets do java e pegar o conteudo do arquivo diretamente do c++, isso que esta me deixando confuso.